# URL matches several Locations. How to perform instructions from the first Location only?

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf

We have following configuration in Apache httpd.conf:

```
<Location /app/srv>
   ...   
   ProxyPass http://localhost:123/srv
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:123/srv

   Header edit Set-Cookie JSESSIONID srv.${ENV}.JSESSIONID
   RequestHeader edit Cookie srv.${ENV}.JSESSIONID JSESSIONID
</Location>

#Following instructions do not work!
#ProxyPass /app/srv !
#ProxyPass /app !

<Location /app >
   ...
   ProxyPass http://localhost:123/app
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:123/app

   Header edit Set-Cookie JSESSIONID app.${ENV}.JSESSIONID
   RequestHeader edit Cookie app.${ENV}.JSESSIONID JSESSIONID
</Location>
```

As far as I can see in case of request with context path /app/srv coockie JSESSIONID will be edited two times.
And in result will be renamed to **srv.${ENV}.app.${ENV}.JSESSIONID**

But I need to rename coockie to **srv.${ENV}.JSESSIONID**

I can see such behavior on one our testing box.
Is it possible to stop processing after "Location /app/srv" directive?

I tried to add instruction "**ProxyPass /app/srv !**" after directive "**Location /app/srv**" but it does not help.

**UPDATE:**
I do not know what full context path could be for /app.
It could be /app/page1, /app/page2, etc.
I only know that there exist /app/srv and /app/something context paths.
And I would like to have different instructions for /app/srv and /app/something context paths.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#locationmatch) to get what you want like this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/app/?$" >
```

That should match /app and /app/ but not /app/srv.

Comment: Actualy I do not know full context path for /app. It could be /app/page1. I only know that there could be /app/srv and /app/<something> context paths. And I would like to have different instructions for /app/srv and /app/<something> context paths.

Comment: In that case matching against ^/app/(?!srv) should match anything starting with /app/ but not followed by srv should match.